# Enlightened badge rules clarification

Tags: discussion, enlightened-badge

Today I [answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19518883/why-can-not-inherit-from-interface/19518909#19518909) on StackOverflow, which was accepted and upvoted 10 times. I received only a *Nice Answer* badge, while I was expecting an *Enlightened* one, as well. My answer was the first one for the question, also.

Do I miss something about the *Enlightened* badge rules ?

Comment: The Enlightened badge sometimes takes longer to award than the Nice Answer badge. Give it some time.

Comment: Haha, that's the only thing I can do, isn't it ? Thanks anyway, I just thought I have misunderstood it's rules. :)

Comment: please wait 6-8 weeks for this badge

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some badges take time to be awarded (there are various background tasks that run in different intervals depending on the badge). Enlightened is one of them. I don't know exactly how often the criteria for this badge are checked but I usually got mine on the same day of receiving the "Nice Answer" badge.

So just be patient. I think for this badge it even makes sense that it's not awarded immediately in case an OP accepts the answer and changes his mind a few minutes later and accepts a different answer.

Comment: Thanks, mate. Now it's clear. :)